# How to find new technosphere providers and change its location in Brightway2

Tags: brightway

I want to create a new dataset on copper production in 'CH', based on the current dataset 'copper production in AU'. I tried to apply the following functions, but the last function returned "Cannot find this location". Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

```
data = w.extract_brightway2_databases(["ecoinvent 3.4 cutoff"])
copper_production = w.contains("name", "copper production")
musuizi=w.get_one(data,w.equals('location','AU'),copper_production)
musuizi2=w.transformations.geo.copy_to_new_location(musuizi, 'CH')
w.transformations.geo.relink_technosphere_exchanges(musuizi2,data,exclusive=True, drop_invalid=False, biggest_first=False, contained=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Note: This question is actually about the wurst library, not Brightway)

It looks like there are some bugs due to sync problems between the ecoinvent database and the geographical definitions. For the time being, you can do the following:

```
import wurst as w
data = w.extract_brightway2_databases(["ecoinvent 3.4 cutoff"])

mapping = {
    "ASCC": "US-ASCC",
    "CSG": "CN-CSG",
    "FRCC": "US-FRCC",
    "HICC": "US-HICC",
    "IAI Area, Africa": 'IAI Area 1, Africa',
    "IAI Area, Asia, without China and GCC": 'IAI Area 4&5, without China',
    "IAI Area, Gulf Cooperation Council": 'IAI Area 8, Gulf',
    "IAI Area, North America, without Quebec": 'IAI Area 2, without Quebec',
    "IAI Area, Russia & RER w/o EU27 & EFTA": 'IAI Area, Europe outside EU & EFTA',
    "IAI Area, South America": 'IAI Area 3, South America',
    "MRO, US only": "US-MRO",
    "NPCC, US only": "US-NPCC",
    "RFC": "US-RFC",
    "SERC": "US-SERC",
    "SGCC": "CN-SGCC",
    "SPP": "US-SPP",
    "TRE": "US-TRE",
    "WECC, US only": "US-WECC",
}


def update_all_locations(data):
    for ds in data:
        ds['location'] = mapping.get(ds['location'], ds['location'])


update_all_locations(data)
copper_in_au = w.get_one(data, w.equals('location','AU'), w.contains("name", "copper production"))
copper_in_ch = w.transformations.geo.copy_to_new_location(copper_in_au, 'CH')
data.append(copper_in_ch)
w.transformations.geo.relink_technosphere_exchanges(
    copper_in_ch,
    data,
    contained=False
)
```

Comment: What is this `w` black magic? `Wurst`? Shall we create a new wurst-specific tag?

Comment: Yes! w is the package "wurst"!

Comment: @ChrisMutel  Hello Chris!  Just following my previous question: now I have created a dataset musuizi2, and how to write it back to the data (or Ecoinvent database)? After the previous steps, if I try to {copper_production = w.contains("name", "copper production")
musuizi=w.get_one(data,w.equals('location','CH'),copper_production)} then it returns error. Does it mean the "transformation" only generate a new dataset instead of changing the "data" itself?

Comment: Good catch! Answer edited to add `copper_in_ch` back into the `data` list.

Comment: @ChrisMutel Thanks for your answering, now I have a new question, now I want to explore the aluminum production:   `alu_in_ra = w.get_one(data, w.equals('location','IAI Area, Russia & RER w/o EU27 & EFTA'), w.contains("name", "aluminium production, primary, liquid, prebake"))` then it returns no result, but  I am pretty sure ecoinvent database has this activity. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Change the location to `IAI Area, Europe outside EU & EFTA` - you updated it in the answer code.